# Broken display of responses

Tags: bug, profile-page, responses

The display of usernames in the list of responses on user profiles is broken, at least on some sites (the screenshot is from meta.cstheory, and for me it’s also broken on stackoverflow, but not on main cstheory):

[image]

Tested in Firefox 72.